# I have opened only one chrome tab but the windows task manager shows 6 chrome processes runnning

Tags: windows, google-chrome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple chrome.exe in Task Manager](https://superuser.com/questions/174652/multiple-chrome-exe-in-task-manager)

What is happening chrome takes so much memory.
Can some one explain

Answer (score 5):

Some of the processes are bound to be plugins and extensions. In the wrench menu, choose Tools → Task Manager to view what processes are being used for.

Right now I have one tab open and yet six processes: One babysitter process, two for LastPass, one for GPU rendering, one for Flash, and one for the actual page I'm viewing.

You can get a somewhat more detailed view of what memory Chrome is using by visiting the URL `about:memory` (can't make a link to it with Markdown).

[image: Google Crome task manager with one tab]