# Google Chrome spawned 12 process for just one tab, is this normal?

Tags: google-chrome, chromium

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple chrome.exe in Task Manager](https://superuser.com/questions/174652/multiple-chrome-exe-in-task-manager)

Lately i noticed that Google chrome unlike Firefox spawns process instead of threads for tabs.But, this time, I had just had one tab open in google chrome, and it spawned 12 process. Is this normal? If yes, why does it need so many process? Does the extensions need individual process?

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Extensions are run in their own processes. In Chrome's Wrench menu, you can go to Tools → Task Manager to see what all the processes are being used for.

[image: Google Chrome task manager]

Comment: +1 for the extensions, but +1 million for the OS X screenshot in answer to the Windows question.

Comment: Who cares, apart from the skin, it looks and works the same on Windows ;)