# High RAM usage by svchost.exe and chrome.exe

Tags: memory

I don't know why while my laptop is sitting idle , it uses a lot of RAM , searching in task manager I found the process *svchost.exe.* , how can I
remove it or is it normal. I have 3GB RAM. and my gadget shows RAM usage over 70%.I have listed all high usage processes shown in task manager.

[image]

**edit**

i have also found chrome stealing my memory , while only one tab of chrome is open.
[image]

Comment: You can try to use process explorer (https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) to investigate what is exactly hidden under the svchost. Your usage is nothing much out of the ordinary but if you are curious - investigate with mentioned tool.

Comment: Just what I see there your using less then 135MB.  Where is the high memory usage exactly?

Comment: svchost.exe.Its a system proccess and host multiple Windows Services(shared service proccess) anyway its duplicate as @DavidPostill said.

Comment: Chrome's open multiple instances, and redoing the @Ramhound question, Where is the high memory usage exactly?

Comment: @ Francisco: chrome is not opened in multiple instances , only one tab is opened.

Comment: [Why are there multiple Chrome instances running even though I only have one window (only one tab) open?](http://superuser.com/q/461552)

Comment: post pictures of RAMMap: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Some Programs(Like viruses) to don't be closed they rename them with svchost.exe.
But I recommend to scan your Computer.Don't try to close them if they are normal i guess it can damage your computer.And Yes Chrome is using Too much Ram in my computer too.