# Chrome has many processes listed

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, process

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple chrome.exe processes in Task Manager](https://superuser.com/questions/174652/multiple-chrome-exe-processes-in-task-manager)

I am a Firefox user. I installed and started using Google Chrome for the past few days and I like it. I use Windows 7.

When I check my Task Manager under Processes I have 9 `Chrome.exe *32` processes for a single window.

Is this normal? Does that mean it is using more system resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because there is Chrome process for each tab currently open and recently closed (so you can restore it easily with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and even background process (update checker etc.)

It will use slightly more system resources as there is an overhead for each process, but the memory etc for each tab will be distributed across these processes rather than being concentrated in one.

The benefit of using separate processes for each tab is that if one process crashes it only takes out that tab and not the whole application.

Comment: I appreciate your help. But I have just one tab open now, Still it shows 9 processes.

Comment: @Ivanka - Not sure. There are other processes that run - I have 19 tabs open but 31 processes. It might include closed tabs too.

Comment: @lvanka I think add-ons and extensions also add to processes.