# why do i have more chrome processes in process-explorer than in chrome task manager?

Tags: google-chrome, process

I currently have 23 Chrome processes running according to process explorer, but Chrome's task manager only lists 19 of them. I am curious to know why the extra processes? Or more pointedly why they're not listed in Chrome's task manager?

Edit: I will point out that there is a question that sounds similar at first glance though the details differ enough to make my question unique from it
[Multiple chrome.exe processes in Task Manager](https://superuser.com/questions/174652/multiple-chrome-exe-processes-in-task-manager)

Comment: Do you only have one Chrome instance open? If you have multiple - especially if any are Incognito or use different profiles - I believe the task manager built into Chrome won't see them.

Comment: multiple windows and tabs but none incognito and each window was opened from inside the program by either clicking and dragging a tab away from it's current window or the context menu of open link in new window on a link in an existing tab